# getTypoLink_URL not working

Tags: typo3

i am working on an existing project. I am tyring to use

```
$params = array(
                            $this->prefixId.'[cmd]' => 'SINGLE',
                            $this->prefixId.'[uid]' => intval( $item['uid'] ),
                            $this->prefixId.'[chash]' => substr( md5( $item['uid'] ), 0, 8 ),
                            $this->prefixId.'[page]' => $this->GPvars['page'],
                        );
$link = '<a href="'.str_replace( '&', '&amp;', $this->pi_getPageLink( $this->conf['pidSingle'], '_self', $params ) ).'" target="_self" title="'.$submarks['###SINGLE###'].'">';
```

$this->pi_getPageLink is not returning anything.

class.tslib_pibase.php is

```
function pi_getPageLink($id,$target='',$urlParameters=array())  {
     return $this->cObj->getTypoLink_URL($id,$urlParameters,$target);

}
```

Comment: Check $this->conf['pidSingle'] if there is a valid value. Check it with an existing page ID! Does your class extend tslib_pibase?

Answer (score 2):

That functions need parameters. You should get error messages. Read the [API](http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/classtslib__c_obj.html#a6e2b01459c401caf9d6e7370da8be830).

```
$this->cObj->getTypoLink_URL(
   123, // ID of the page where you link to
   array('test' => 1, 'bar' => 'yes'),
   ''
);
```

But i usually use the typolink function. You can use there any typoscript option for typolink:

```
$this->cObj->stdWrap_typolink(
   '',  
   array(
      'returnLast' => 'url',
      'parameter' => 123,
      'additionalParams' => '&test=1&bar=yes',
   )
);
```

Comment: i was already passing parameters but still it returns empty string. Also, i tried to use $this->cObj->stdWrap_typolink but it also returns empty string.

Comment: just edit your question and paste the code you use. Check if the PID you use is correct and the page is visible.

Answer (score 1):

This solution can't work:

```
$this->cObj->stdWrap_typolink(
   '',  
   array(
      'returnLast' => 'url',
      'parameter' => 123,
      'additionalParams' => '&test=1&bar=yes',
   )
);
```

This one works:

```
$this->cObj->stdWrap_typolink(
   '',  
   array('typolink' => array(
      'returnLast' => 'url',
      'parameter' => 123,
      'additionalParams' => '&test=1&bar=yes',
   )
);
```